# cert-manager issuing too many same certificates when a multi-domains ingress is updated

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

We're using kubernetes with ingresses, cert-manager (v1.9.1) and the letsencrypt issuer.
Our use case is the following:
We have a multitenant solution with 3 services that allows people to change their domain names (1 for each service).
Each time someone is changing a domain name, it triggers the update of the ingress related to the service. This update triggers the generation of a new order by the cert manager.

We meet 2 issues:

- When someone is changing one domain name (making it replaced in the spec.tls[] and spec.rules[] sections of the ingress), the order created seems to regenerate all the letsencrypt certificates from the ingress and not only the one changed (which leads to the letsencrypt issue "too many certificates already issued" after some tries).
- When one of the certificates of an order has an error (due to the previous issue, "too many certificates already issued"), the other certificates in the order (that do normally not have any problem) seem not to be generated either.

What would be the best strategy to avoid these issues with our use case? (Maybe we would have to create one ingress by domain name? Or is there a way to have one order by certificate and not to trigger the regeneration of existing certificates on the update of an ingress?)

--- EDITED ---

Here is the ingress (with {hidden} fields and renaming for privacy):

```yaml
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: server-ingress
  namespace: {hidden}
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test1.customer-domain.fr
        - test1.our-company.com
        - test2.our-company.com
      secretName: our-company-server-tls
  rules:
    - host: test1.customer-domain.fr
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: server-v3-24-5
              servicePort: 8080
    - host: test1.our-company.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: server-v3-24-5
              servicePort: 8080
    - host: test2.our-company.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: server-v3-24-5
              servicePort: 8080
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: {hidden}
```

Thank you,

Comment: seems like you are using `http01` challenge, use DNS challenge and you will not get  the max issue

Comment: > the order created seems to regenerate all the letsencrypt certificates from the ingress and not only the one changed, No it does not regenerate all, but if frequent change for same subdomain then it will happen

Comment: Can you use wildcard certificates, covering all domains/subdomains for your users. don't generate new certs for each change: make sure end-user creates their ingress in their subdomain?

Comment: https://letsdebug.net/, my fav tool, this will tell you about the number of certs issued for each sub domain and why you are getting the max limit. another option can be a wild card which is mentioned @SYN, and use that at controller level as a default

Comment: We were using http01 and maybe we will have to keep it as some of our customers have custom domains that they configure to target our cluster (on their own)... We have changed the issuer yesterday to include both http01 (for custom domains) and dns01 (for our wildcard one via OVH), but we are still wondering if a http01 bad certificate would make fail all the Order and maybe block other certificates to be issued as well.

Comment: @Adiii All of the subdomains in the ingress where we added a new one seemed to have a new certificate issued actually :/

Comment: @Adiii Thank you for the tool! Still, as a limit has been reached with letsencrypt, it seems it can not list certificates (and crt.sh only shows us precertificates)...

Comment: in the expected behaviour, it should not recreate the certs for other domain, can you show the ingress config? whats the secret name for each domain, it might be expected if the secret name remain same for all the ingress, so I will recommend to keep different secret name for different domain. normally a secret name should be same as domain. for example `abc.com` is domain then keep the secret name is `abc.com`. so it will give you the uniqueness and the order will not recreate for all

Comment: recently discovered this behaviour with one of my client with bad requirements, which I tickle like this which I explain above

Comment: Thank you @Adiii, I updated the description with the ingress... Actually, the secret is in fact always the same as you pointed out... So I should create as many secrets as spec.tls.hosts[]? (So maybe in separate ingresses? Or how to make each secret match each host in the spec.tls.hosts section?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248677/discussion-between-adiii-and-corentin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The order created seems to regenerate all the letsencrypt certificates from the ingress and not only the one changed

Based on the discussion, This is because you are using the same secret name for all the ingress, you need to have a different secret name for each host in TLS in the ingress and this way it will not recreate all certs order.

So this should work,

```
  tls:
    - secretName: test1.customer-domain.fr
      hosts:
        - test1.customer-domain.fr
    - secretName: test1.our-company.com
      hosts:
        - test1.our-company.com
  rules:
    - host: test1.customer-domain.fr
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: server-v3-24-5
              servicePort: 8080
    - host: test1.our-company.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: server-v3-24-5
              servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: I will configure this way... But unfortunately, due to the letsencrypt's reached limitation, I could really test only on Thursday. I'll comment then, and probably select your answer as accepted if everything works :) You seem to know this case so I'm hopeful! Thank you again

Comment: yeah and meanwhile you can also test like `test1.temp.our-company.com`, try a different subdomain

Comment: I thought all the domain was blocked (50 certificates/week), but I haven't tried with subdomains of subdomains, I'll give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: The generation of the certificate of a subdomain's subdomain gives the same error as for subdomains ("too many certificates already issued for: {domain name}"). I will come back to you here on Thursday. The Orders seem now separated thanks to the different secrets, so half of the point seems already confirmed as solved!

Comment: Hi there! I had to change some k8s configuration to make things more maintenable (a ClusterIssuer instead of an Issuer applied to multiple namespaces), then I could test and it seems to work. :) Thank you!